# How does USB-C powerbank know if I want it to charge or be charged?

Tags: charger, usb-c, laptop

A while back, I tried to use a USB-C powerbank (I think it was a Ravpower "PD Pioneer 20000 mAh, 60 W Portable Charger") to charge a laptop that was powered by USB-C (a new Lenovo).  The laptop works fine with a 60 - 65 W charger, and will still charge when closed with a less powerful charger.  The problem I had, though, was that whenever I plugged the powerbank into the computer, the power always went from the computer to the powerbank, the computer tried to charge the powerbank rather than the powerbank charging the computer.

With older powerbanks there was typically a dedicated 'in' (typically Micro USB) port and one or more dedicated 'out' ports (typically USB-A), but with most USB-C powerbanks I've seen, there is a single USB-C port used for charging the powerbank and for charging USB-C devices.  In most situations, e.g. plugging into a wall charger, or a phone or tablet I can see that there is no ambiguity about which way the power flows, but in those ambiguous cases, how does it know what I want it to do?

In practical terms, I guess my question is, if I buy a USB-C powerbank with sufficient power to charge my laptop, how do I know I won't run into the same problem?  In all the product specs, descriptions and ads, it seems to just magically work.  Am I missing something?

Comment: I see that this question was closed as "off-topic".  Is there a better stackexchange site on which to ask this queston?  In any case, to me this is a very important question related to the design of usb-c powerbanks, which should (IMOSHO) include a clear and unambiguous way to specify whether they are to charge or be charged.  As an experienced stackoverflow user, it's been my experience that over-zealous purity enforcement lessens the value of the site for everyone.

Comment: I agree that closing this question is odd.  Rather than close it can it be moved to another StackExchange forum?  Superuser perhaps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When connecting two USB-C devices, and both support sourcing and sinking power, then they will take a guess on which is intended to source power and which is intended to sink power.  If the default behavior is not what is desired then disconnecting and reconnecting is supposed to rectify this.  This behavior has lead people to believe that there is a "directionality" to a USB-C cable because they will disconnect the cable, flip it end for end, then reconnect and see power flow the opposite direction.  It is not the flipping of the cable that redirects power flow but the disconnecting and reconnecting.

What also happens is people will disconnect and reconnect so quickly that not enough time passes for the devices to see that the cable was disconnected in the first place.  Also, if disconnected long enough the devices "forget" that they were connected and will reset to their default preferences of being a power source or power sink.  I do wish that there was an easily accessible setting in software on computers to set this preferred behavior but as this is not the case we are where we are.

I know of one thing you could consider doing to enforce the direction of power flow, but only 12 watts of power.  Consider a USB-C/male to USB-A/female adapter on the power bank, a USB-C/male to USB-A/male cable on the computer, and connect the adapter and cable together.  I suggest this as you likely have these on hand.

What you could also consider is a dock of some sort between the computer and power bank.  I have a "mini-dock" that has a USB-C power input port that connects to the computer by a captive USB-C cable.  Since the dock is incapable of putting power out its USB-C port I could put this in the connection path to a power bank and know that power would always flow from the power bank to the laptop.  The small problem with this is the dock is going to consume some tiny amount of this power for its own electronics.  Again, a small amount, but this should be kept in mind if it is important to maximize the energy transfer from the power bank battery to the laptop battery.  Also keep in mind that a dock could be the weakest link in a chain on power transfer.  If the power bank and power cable are capable of 100 watts of power transfer, but the dock is only capable of 60 watts, then you are going get only 60 watts to the laptop.  Considering the dock in the chain removes all doubt of which direction power flows I'd consider the downsides acceptable.

With your mention of Lenovo I'm reminded of Lenovo power banks and laptops retaining their vendor specific power ports in addition to using USB-C.  You may want to look for a Lenovo power bank, or any brand really that uses some kind of non-USB power port in addition to USB-C.  These alternatives to USB-C will almost certainly lack the ambiguity on which direction the power should flow.

Answer (score 1):

With USB-PD the two devices negotiate which will source and which will sink current. On a lot of more sophisticated devices like phones and tablets you can configure which way way current will go (e.g. use one phone to charge another).

If your devices don't allow you to choose then you have to hope they pick good defaults. If they don't, you can try quickly unplugging and replugging in case they alternate roles. Failing that you'd have to buy smarter devides.